# Python 3 Type Comparisons

Tags: python, types

So I am trying to override the **eq** operator of a custom class, but in doing so I want to check that the two objects are the same type, so that I can compare the attributes within them.

MyScript.py

```
class myClass:
   def __init__(val):
      self.myVar = val

   def __eq__(self, other):
      assert type(other) is type(self)
      return self.myVar == other.myVar
```

MyFunc.py

```
from MyScript import *
def myFunc(val):
   return myClass(val)
```

The above two are within a MyPackage package

My main looks similar to this
main.py

```
from MyPackage import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
   a = myClass(1)
   b = myFunc(1)

   print(a == b)
```

However I am getting an assertion error saying that the two objects are of different classes

```
type(a) == "<MyPackage.myClass>"
type(b) == "<myClass>"
```

I didn't write all of my code out, but is there something I am missing with Python 3 that is stopping the classes from being the same when they are created from different places?

Comment: don't use `is` to compare types - use `==`
Also Do you really want to generate an assertion error from the __eq__ method - seems odd that doing `MyClass(3) == 3` (for example) would generate an AssertionError, rather than True or False.

Comment: After some fixing up of self parameters, your code works. Those two different types mean that `myClass.py` has been imported differently in different modules. Once as `myClass` and once as `package.myClass`. Two separate modules with unique namespaces and thus different definitions of the same class. Maybe you've done something with the python path so that this two conflicting imports don't raise an error.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 
I have tried

type(self) == type(other)
type(self) is type(other)
isinstance(other, type(self)
isinstance(other, myClass)

None pass the assertion.

the __eq__ is doing a lot more than just checking one value, so yes I want to make sure that the code will not run if you are trying to compare unlike types in this instance.

Comment: @tdelaney

This might be it, the same package is being used all over the place, perhaps I have different ways of importing it (will check all the instances). What got me was that this was working in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.7

Comment: @TheIronDuckling For __eq__ to raise AssertionError (when asserts are turned on) makes no sense to me - __eq__ should return True or False.

Comment: @tdelaney - Those two 'paths' to MyClass isn't a confliction import and should not ever cause an error. In the MyClass module the class will always be an unqualified class name (i.e no dotted path).

Comment: @tdelaney had the issue here
Sorry for not explaining myself correctly>
my class was defined in one file, my function in another and the main in another.
The function was importing the class by
```from MyClass import *```
where my main was importing it by
```from myClass.MyClass import *```

And so python was seeing them as two different classes.

Changing to a relative import worked

```from .MyClass import *```

Comment: Interesting. It seems like you have a bad entry in your python path or `from MyClass import *` wouldn't have worked. Sometimes .py files add their own directory to the path to get around package installation problems but that can lead to problems like this one later on.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Yeah I used to have the __eq__ returning False when the types didnt match, but when others were using the package they didnt realise why things werent being compared. so I simply made their code not run if they tried to use it wrong.

Probably a smoother, less passive aggressive way would be to do the check, and throw an error, but still return False and continue the code

Comment: @TheIronDuckling - What sort of error would you throw, and once you throw an exception you can't then return False. TBH If the users of your code don't understand why things are returning False, then either make it clear in your documentation that what comparisons work, or at least raise a NotImplementedError ot TypeError (with a clear message) to explain that comparisons aren't defined. An AssertionError is not an error a User should ever see (and of course they go away entirely if the -O option is used or DEBUG is set to False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by an errant import. But there is another way to check the instances that is worth considering. Your solution doesn't work for inheritors of `myClass`. Instead you could do

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(val):
        self.myVar = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, myClass):
            return self.myVar == other.myVar
        else: 
            raise TypeError(f"'==' not supported between instances of '{self.__class__.__name__}' and '{other.__class__.__name__}'")
```

It would work for child classes of `myClass` and raises the more typical error.

Comment: Yes it was a difference in import methods. the __class__.__name__ is a good tip! I didn't know that I could get just the name of the class!

Thank you.

As a side note, with the bad imports, even the isinstance(other, myClass) didnt return True

Comment: @TheIronDuckling - yeah, its a bit of a mind bender that `package.myClass` and `myClass` are two different modules from python's perspective, even if its the same .py file.

Comment: O.P. is almost surely falling into the [double import trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap).

Comment: @wim - Thanks for the link. The way I've seen it happen is that hacks are made so that a set of modules can import without doing an install. Later, the project is gathered into a larger package but the hacks remain.